# cross product and RHR

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

**Edit**: I really like the approach taken by $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the comments below. I posted this late last night and didn't get to ask him why $\bf R(a \times b) = Ra \times Rb$ for any rotation matrix $\bf R$. I'm not sure how to prove that: along with trying to evaluate the determinant directly, I looked in a linear algebra book and tried using the "norm-preserving" property of rotation matrices to evaluate $|\bf R(a \times b) - R(a) - R(b)|$ $^2$, but didn't succeed. How do you do this?

---

In one of my courses, a professor briefly summarized properties of the cross product at the start of last class. I realized that the assertion

$$ \bf a \times (b + c) = a\times b + a\times c$$

was actually surprising to me. Clearly this is fundamental (if you don't accept this, you can't derive a way of *computing* the cross product), but the proof is a bit slippery.

If you start from $\bf{ a \times  b}$ $:= \bf \hat n |a||b|$ $ \sin\theta$, where $ \bf \hat n$ comes from the right hand rule, then if you can prove as a lemma $\bf a \cdot (b \times c) = (a \times b) \cdot c$, then there's a neat little proof which I found [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=518647). But the only argument I've seen for the needed lemma is about the volume of a parallelepiped, which only convinces me that $\bf | a \cdot (b \times c)| = |(a \times b) \cdot c|$.

I think I prefer the approach in one of my textbooks, which starts by defining the cross product by determinants - so, distributivity holds - and proves most of the needed properties. But it wusses out at a crucial point: "it can be proven that the orthogonal vector obtained from this matrix obeys the Right Hand Rule".

Could somebody either prove that lemma, or the textbook claim? (Preferably the latter.)

Comment: Interesting question. The first thing we need to answer the second question is a rigorous formalization of the right-hand rule. Up till now I've always thought of the determinantal definition as being that formalization...

Comment: How's this? Consider the rotation matrix $\mathbf R$ such that $\mathbf R\mathbf a$ lies along the positive $x$-axis, and $\mathbf R\mathbf b$ lies in the $xy$-plane with $y\ge0$, and prove that $\mathbf R(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)=\mathbf R\mathbf a\times\mathbf R\mathbf b$ lies along the positive $z$-axis.

Comment: @$\mathbb{R}^n$ So, basically, you can rotate the whole (stiffly-connected) three of 'em into something plainly a right-handed system? Huh. All right: proceed, good sir. (Or, wait, is it obvious how to show this?)

Comment: (Aw, geez, how do I raise this guy on the horn if the @ signals don't ping him?)

Comment: It's fine, I see your comments. Has your textbook proved that rotations preserve cross products? If so, then you're basically done: $(a_x,0,0)\times(b_x,b_y,0)$ is what?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, distributivity is *assumed* (more broadly, we assume the product is linear in each of its arguments, or that it is bilinear).  Without this, even if one defines the action of the cross product on basis vectors, one would be hard-pressed to talk about its action on arbitrary vectors, as these are built up linearly from basis elements.

In short, one uses bilinearity to build up other results, not vice versa.

Furthermore, note that if $\hat n$ comes from a "left-hand rule" instead, none of the logic is really affected.  As long as the cross product is internally consistent, there's no issue.  The determinant approach accomplishes this by imposing an orientation, but this fundamentally gets one of the punchlines of linear algebra backwards.  Using determinants to talk about cross products is backwards.  One should instead use cross products to infer things about determinants.

Or better yet, not use cross products at all, but that's a whole 'nother argument.  Using wedge products, for instance, the equivalent of $a \cdot (b \times c) = (a \times b) \cdot c$ is $(a \wedge b) \wedge c = a \wedge (b \wedge c)$, which is trivially true because wedge products *are* associative, and there's nothing to prove.

Comment: I suspected starting with the linear algebra was the right way to go. :) But how can I show that, if I assume a right-handed coordinate system, the right-hand-rule works?

Comment: "One should instead use cross products to infer things about determinants." How would that work for vector spaces other than $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Regarding proving the right-hand-rule: the easy answer is that we define the cross product so that $\hat x \times \hat y = \hat z$ and so on, hard-coding the right-hand rule into the product. The longer answer is that a right-handed coordinate system induces an orientation on a unit volume. The cross product takes two vectors, determines the oriented plane they span, and then returns the vector that completes a volume so that it has the same orientation as the coordinate system. As far as determinants in $\mathbb R^n$, of course you use the wedge product there.

Comment: Actually, strike that.  The RHR only comes in when we interpret the coordinate system as right-handed.  An equation like $\hat x \times \hat y = \hat z$ only tells us a relationship between basis vectors.  There's no reason the system couldn't be left-handed.  It's just that we *know* the coordinate system is right-handed.