# Rotations preserve cross products?

Tags: linear-algebra

In relation to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296082/cross-product-and-rhr), I'm trying to prove that $\bf R(a \times b) = R(a) \times R(b)$ for any given rotation $\bf R$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Edit:** If one can prove that this holds for the unit vectors (e.g. $\bf R(\hat j) \times R(\hat k) = R(\hat i)$) then that's all there is to it, given the distributivity of cross product and linearity of $\bf R$.

Comment: Do you know about the relationship between quaternions and rotations/cross products on $\Bbb{R}^3$? Because if you're comfortable with that, there's a really short, straightforward proof.

Comment: @Micah No, I do not; but if you'd like to provide a sketch, I'd be happy to brush up. :)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264771/cross-product-and-pseudovector-confusion, in which it is proved that orthogonal operators preserve the cross product within a factor of $\pm 1$ (positive for rotations, negative for reflections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any rotation in $\Bbb{R}^3$ can be represented by $R_x(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_y(\gamma)$, where 
$$\begin{alignat}{1}
R_x(\theta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\[3pt]
0 & \sin \theta  & \cos \theta \\[3pt]
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
R_y(\theta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & 0 & \sin \theta \\[3pt]
0 & 1 & 0 \\[3pt]
-\sin \theta & 0 & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
R_z(\theta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{alignat}
$$
If we show that a rotation around one axis preserves the cross product then we know that the rotation around the others preserves it as well because the arithemetic is analogous and we can apply, for example, $R_x$ to all elements in the equality
$$R_y(\beta)R_y(\gamma)(a \times b) = R_y(\beta)R_y(\gamma)a \times R_y(\beta)R_y(\gamma) b$$

So we have 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\[3pt]
a_2\\[3pt]
a_3\\
\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\[3pt]
b_2\\[3pt]
b_3\\
\end{bmatrix}=\\
\begin{bmatrix}
-a_3b_2\cos\theta +a_2b_3\cos\theta - a_3b_1\sin\theta + a_1b_3\sin\theta\\[3pt]
a_3b_1\cos\theta -a_1b_3\cos\theta - a_3b_2\sin\theta + a_2b_3\sin\theta\\[3pt]
-a2b1\cos^2\theta + a_1b_2\cos^2\theta-a_2b_1\sin^2\theta +a_1b_2\sin^2\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}=\\
\begin{bmatrix}
 (-a_3b_2+a_2b_3)\cos\theta+(-a_3b_1+a_1b_3)\sin\theta\\[3pt]
 (a_3b_1-a_1b_3)\cos\theta+(-a_3b_2+a_2b_3)\sin\theta\\[3pt]
a_1b_2-a_2b_1\\[3pt]
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which you will see is equal to 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\[3pt]
a_2\\[3pt]
a_3\\
\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\[3pt]
b_2\\[3pt]
b_3\\
\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

We can think of $\Bbb{R}^3$ as the space of imaginary [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) $\{ai+bj+ck|i,j,k \in \Bbb{R}\}$. Then the following facts are standard (the first one is in the linked wikipedia article, and the other two are easy to verify given a quaternion multiplication table):

- Any rotation on $\Bbb{R}^3$ may be realized as the conjugate action of some unit quaternion: that is, given any rotation $\bf{R}$, there is some unit quaternion $q({\bf R})$ such that ${\bf R}x=q({\bf R})x q({\bf R})^{-1}$.
- Conjugating by a unit quaternion commutes with taking its imaginary part: if $q$ is a unit quaternion and $r$ an arbitrary quaternion, then
  $$
  q\Im(r)q^{-1}=\Im(qrq^{-1})
  $$
- If $x,y \in \Bbb{R}^3$, their quaternion product is given in terms of the ordinary vector dot product and cross product:
  $$
  xy=-x \cdot y+x \times y \, ;
  $$
  in particular, $x \times y = \Im(xy)$.

If you believe all three of these facts, the proof you want is immediate. Setting $q=q({\bf R})$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf R}(x \times y) &=& q(x \times y)q^{-1}\\
& = &q\Im(xy)q^{-1}\\
&=&\Im(qxyq^{-1})\\
&=&\Im((qxq^{-1})(qyq^{-1}))\\
&=&qxq^{-1} \times qyq^{-1} \\
&=&{\bf R}x \times {\bf R}y
\end{eqnarray}
as desired.