# Inverting non-square matrix with cross-product

Tags: matrices, inverse, rotations

I want to solve for $R$ given $V$, $B$:
$$V_{3x2} = R_{3x3}B_{3x2}$$

Where $R$ is a rotation (orthogonal) matrix, and the columns of $B$ are orthogonal (but not of the same length in general).

1. Do the above facts imply the the columns of $V$ are also orthogonal?
2. Why is it valid to solve for $R$ by creating new matrices $V'_{3x3}$ and $B'_{3x3}$ where the 3rd column is the cross product of the first two columns, and then setting $R = V'_{3x3}(B'_{3x3})^{-1}$?  See section "B. Orientation Determination" of [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Shuang_Song/publication/258793107_An_Electromagnetic_Localization_and_Orientation_Method_Based_on_Rotating_Magnetic_Dipole/links/5834f49108aef19cb81f9218/An-Electromagnetic-Localization-and-Orientation-Method-Based-on-Rotating-Magnetic-Dipole.pdf), where this is performed without justification.

Comment: I haven't looked at the paper, but, if I have perpendicular, length one vectors say $v$ and $w$ then $[v|w|v \times w]$ is a rotation matrix, that is, it is a matrix $R$ with $R^TR=I$ and $\text{det}(R)=1$.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Yes I agree with you on that, however the length of the vectors are not one in general (I will add an edit).

Comment: @abc It doesn't matter that $v$ and $w$ are length $1$: they just need to have matching lengths (that is, the first column $V$ must have the same length as the first column of $B$, etc.).  Rescaling the column by a non-zero scalar makes no difference to the matrix equation.

Comment: @ErickWong Okay, let me clarify further by saying that they are not in general the same value.

Comment: @abc They can't possibly be different if they are the result of multiplying by a rotation matrix: rotation doesn't change length!

Comment: @ErickWong Okay, maybe I am misunderstanding what is being talked about, but I am referring to the vectors of $B$, which are transformed by the rotation matrix into the vectors of $V$

Comment: @abc Yeah I'm saying that as long as the first vector of $V$ has the same length as the first vector of $B$ (which I think we agree it should), and similarly for the second, then just rescale them to one and James's argument still applies.  The rescaling has no effect on the value of $R$, since if $Rv = w$ then also $R(5v) = 5w$.

Comment: @ErickWong Okay, I see.  It sounds equivalent to post-mutliplying with a diagonal matrix.  So does this answer questions (1) or (2)?  I expect (1) to be true just from intuition about what a rotation matrix does, but I don't know how to prove.

Comment: @abc Yes, that's a good way to look at it.  I've now answered 1, and gave some references and an intuition for 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, since rotations preserve dot products, specifically if $R$ is a rotation matrix and $u,v$ are compatible-length column vectors then $u\cdot v = u^Tv = u^TR^TRv = (Ru)^T(Rv) = (Ru)\cdot(Rv)$.  Consequently, rotations do not affect orthogonality, the length of a vector, and the angle between two vectors.
2. The essential fact being asserted here is that if $v,w \in \mathbb R^3$ are orthogonal, and $R$ is a $3\times 3$ rotation matrix, then $R(v\times w) = (Rv) \times (Rw)$.  In fact this holds generally even when $v,w$ are not orthogonal.  Once you believe this is true then it makes sense to extract a third column as the cross product of the first two, since it too satisfies the matrix relation.  One can see a couple mechanical proofs of this at [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296858/rotations-preserve-cross-products), and it can also be seen by tensor analysis.  but you might still wonder why the authors felt it so obvious that it doesn't require proof.

   Effectively, this is saying that the cross product is somewhat intrinsic: it doesn't care how you rotate your coordinate system, it still points in the same direction (but it is sensitive to rescaling the axes so it's not entirely intrinsic).

   The property proved in 1 helps to see intuitively why this is so: the magnitude of $u \times v$ is determined by $\|u\|, \|v\|$ and the angle between them, so it is invariant under rotation.  Likewise, when $u,v$ are non-parallel in $\mathbb R^3$, the direction of $u \times v$ is the basically-unique direction perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$, and so rotation commutes nicely with this as well.  This direction is unique up to negation, and here the "right-hand rule" comes in to disambiguate: the cross-product is the one that makes the triple-product of $u,v,u\times v$ positive.

   If you think about this algebraically, this corresponds to the convention that a rotation matrix has $\det(R) = 1$ (when $\det(R) = -1$ it's a reflection).  Hence a hint as to why the authors called the section "Orientation Determination": there are two orthogonal matrices that map the columns of $B$ to the columns of $V$, but only one is a genuine rotation (hence orientation-preserving).

Comment: Okay thanks, I get it now.  Basically, since two non-parallel vectors uniquely define a third vector (I assume the 'right hand rule' applies), then it uniquely defines the rotation.  However, if there was only one vector (or two parallel vectors), then there would be ambiguity as to which rotations (e.g. sequence of Euler angles) were applied.

Comment: @abc Yup, if it's only one independent vector there exists a one-parameter family of solutions (we can freely multiply by rotations about that single axis).